# How can I extract some parts of a PHP string that are separated by spaces

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace, explode

My PHP strings look like this:

```
$test1= ' &nbsp; 1    AAA vs SSS    ';
$test2= '  2        GGG vs FFF ';
```

I need to extract the NUMBER, the names from the strings :

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [no] => 1
        [one] => AAA 
        [two] => SSS    
    )
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what is array for , desired output ?

Comment: regex is a good starting point. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\s|&nbsp;)*([0-9:]+)\s+(\S.*\S)\svs\s(\S.*\S)\s*$
```

in the replace, time will be in $1
home team in $2
away team in $3
(and the score for the third match will be 0-3)

[Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/fY5uF3/1)

In your PHP file :

```
$game1 = ' 04:60    FC Heidenheim 1846 vs SV Sandhausen    ';
//I strip the &nbsp;'s first to have a simpler regexp
$game1 = str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',$game1);
preg_match ("@^\s*([0-9:]+)\s+(\S.*\S)\svs\s(\S.*\S)\s*$@", $game1, $matches); 
$result =new stdClass;
$result->time = $matches[1];
$result->hometeam = $matches[2];
$result->awayteam = $matches[3];

var_dump( $result );
```

Comment: Using preg_match() :   
preg_match ("@^\s*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s+(\S.*\S)\svs\s(\S.*\S)\s*$@", $game1, $matches);
echo $matches[1].' '.$matches[2].' - '.$matches[3];

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it works like you want ;)

Comment: yes but it does not work for this case :  &nbsp; 1    AAA vs SSS

Comment: Your question was orginally "11:11 AA A vs S SS" ;)

Comment: It wasnt in the original mesage because it was hidden, i didnt knew that i had a nbsp there i thought it was a blank space

Comment: This example dont have nbsp inside it. i think you sent the wrong url

Comment: In my PHP code I suggest to replace first the nbsp's with a str_replace, then apply the regexp. Otherwise the regexp will be very heavy with \s|&nbsp; everywhere instead of simple \s

Answer (score 0):

you should use trim() on your string,
after it if the structure string does not change:

```
$game = trim($game);

$hour = substr($game,0,5);

$opponents = substr($game, 6);

$opponents = explode("vs",$opponents);
```

so the array look

```
array(
'hour'=>$hour,
'home_team'=>$opponents[0],
'away_team'=>$opponents[1] );
```

i didnt test it but it s look like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know  PHP, but you can use the below regex to get the values. `group 1` will have the time, `group 2` will have the home team name and `group 3` will have the away team name.

```
^([\d:]+)\s+([\w\s\d]+)\s+vs\s+([\w\s\d]+)\s?$
```

[Here you can see the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/oV2gS6/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like,

```
$test1= ' 1    AAA vs SSS    ';
$test2= '  2        GGG vs FFF ';

$test1 = dataFormatter($test1);
$test2 = dataFormatter($test2);

print_r($test1);
print_r($test2);

function dataFormatter($data)
{
    $data= explode(" ",$data);
    foreach($data as $value)
    {
        if($value && $value!= vs)
            $newData[] = $value;
    }
    return $newData;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => AAA
[2] => SSS
)

Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => GGG
[2] => FFF
)
```